# pass structure with arrays as parameters to a function in a C++ dll issue

Tags: visual-c++, struct, dll, powerbuilder

I'm a PB 12.5 user and I  was trying to call a function which is dll written by VC++ likes:

```
typedef struct clientinfo_struct{
   const char* mdtrt_cert_type;
   const char * mdtrt_cert_no; 
   const char * card_sn; 
   const char * begntime;
   const char * psn_cert_type; 
   const char * certno; 
   const char * psn_name;
}clientinfo_struct;

typedef struct clientinfo_baseinfo_ret_struct{
    char * psn_no; 
    char * psn_cert_type; 
    char * certno; 
    char * psn_name;
    char * gend; 
    char * naty; 
    char * brdy; 
    double age;
    }clientinfo_baseinfo_ret_struct;

   typedef struct clientinfo_insuinfo_ret_struct{
        int insuinforecordscount; 
        double * balc; 
        char ** insutype; 
        char ** psn_type;
        char ** psn_insu_stas;
        char ** psn_insu_date;
        char ** paus_insu_date;
        char ** cvlserv_flag;
        char ** insuplc_admdvs;
        char ** emp_name;

  }clientinfo_insuinfo_ret_struct;

  typedef struct clientinfo_idetinfo_ret_struct{
        int  idetinforecordscount; 
        char ** psn_idet_type; 
        char ** psn_type_lv; 
        char ** memo;
        char ** begntime; 
        char ** endtime;
  }clientinfo_idetinfo_ret_struct;



int getclientinfo(general_struct & gs,
  clientinfo_struct & cs,
  clientinfo_baseinfo_ret_struct & cbrs,
  clientinfo_insuinfo_ret_struct & cinsurs,
  clientinfo_idetinfo_ret_struct & cidenrs,
  general_ret_struct & grs)
```

I tried to call this function from PB, it doesn't work, the code like below

I declared the function in Global external function section

```
   function long  getclientinfo(general_struct   gs,&
    clientinfo_struct   cs,&
    ref clientinfo_baseinfo_ret_struct   cbrs,&
    ref clientinfo_insuinfo_ret_struct   cinsurs,&
    ref clientinfo_idetinfo_ret_struct   cidenrs,&
    ref general_ret_struct   grs) &
    LIBRARY "dgnewsbsapi.dll"  Alias for 'getclientinfo;Ansi'
```

the I tried to use it

```
  clientinfo_baseinfo_ret_struct cbrs1
 
cbrs1.psn_no =space(35)
cbrs1.psn_cert_type =space(10)
cbrs1.certno = space(55)
cbrs1.psn_name = space(55)
cbrs1.gend = space(10)
cbrs1.naty =space(10)
cbrs1.brdy = space(30)
cbrs1.age = 0.0

clientinfo_insuinfo_ret_struct cirs1

long ll_row
 

 
 
 cirs1.insuinforecordscount=0
 
  //try to initialize cidrs1
 
 for ll_row=1 to 50
     cirs1.balc [ll_row]= 0.0;
    cirs1.insutype [ll_row]= space(10);
    cirs1.psn_type [ll_row]= space(10);
    cirs1.psn_insu_stas[ll_row] =  space(10);
    cirs1.psn_insu_date[ll_row] = space(30);
    cirs1.paus_insu_date[ll_row] =  space(30);
    cirs1.cvlserv_flag[ll_row] = space(10);
    cirs1.insuplc_admdvs[ll_row] = space(10);
    cirs1.emp_name[ll_row] =  space(200);
    
next


    

 string ls_psn_idet_type[50],ls_psn_type_lv[50]
 string ls_memo[50],ls_begntime[50],ls_endtime[50]
  //try to initialize cidrs1
 for ll_row=1 to 50
    
    ls_psn_idet_type[ll_row] =space(6);
    ls_psn_type_lv[ll_row] = space(6);
    ls_memo[ll_row] = space(500);
    ls_begntime[ll_row] = space(30);
    ls_endtime[ll_row] =space(30);
    
next




clientinfo_idetinfo_ret_struct cidrs1
cidrs1.idetinforecordscount = 0

 //try to initialize cidrs1
  for ll_row=1 to 50
    cidrs1.psn_idet_type[ll_row] =space(6);
    cidrs1.psn_type_lv[ll_row] = space(6);
    cidrs1.memo[ll_row] = space(500);
    cidrs1.begntime[ll_row] = space(30);
    cidrs1.endtime[ll_row] =space(30);
 next


 


 ll_result = getclientinfo(gs1, cs1, cbrs1, cirs1, cidrs1, grs1)
```

it was crashed when it called this function, I tried to debug it in PB, I found the cbrs1,cbrs1,cidrs1 have initialized

[image]

[image]

but when I tired to debug the dll in VC++ (my verison was 2013)

the project was carshed in the line of code which it assigned the value to the variable of arrays,it looks like it's uninitialized

[image]

please compare the pic below which I tried debug  and the variables were different which I called it from C++ which works fine ,[image]

I have no idea what's equivalent of C++ like code below in PB, this C++ works for me

```
 clientinfo_baseinfo_ret_struct cbrs1;
 
 cbrs1.psn_no = new char[50];
 cbrs1.psn_cert_type = new char[50];
 cbrs1.certno = new char[50];
 cbrs1.psn_name = new char[50];
 cbrs1.gend = new char[50];
 cbrs1.naty = new char[50];
 cbrs1.brdy = new char[50];
 cbrs1.age = 0.0;

 clientinfo_insuinfo_ret_struct cirs1;
 cirs1.insuinforecordscount = 0;
 cirs1.balc = new double[5];
 cirs1.insutype = new char*[5];
 cirs1.psn_type = new char*[5];
 cirs1.psn_insu_stas = new char*[5];
 cirs1.psn_insu_date = new char*[5];
 cirs1.paus_insu_date = new char*[5];
 cirs1.cvlserv_flag = new char*[5];
 cirs1.insuplc_admdvs = new char*[5];
 cirs1.emp_name = new char*[5];

 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
    cirs1.balc[i] = 0.0;
    cirs1.insutype[i] = new char[50];
    cirs1.psn_type[i] = new char[50];
    cirs1.psn_insu_stas[i] = new char[50];
    cirs1.psn_insu_date[i] = new char[50];
    cirs1.paus_insu_date[i] = new char[50];
    cirs1.cvlserv_flag[i] = new char[50];
    cirs1.insuplc_admdvs[i] = new char[50];
    cirs1.emp_name[i] = new char[50];
 }



 clientinfo_idetinfo_ret_struct cidrs1;
 cidrs1.idetinforecordscount = 0;
 cidrs1.psn_idet_type = new char*[5];
 cidrs1.psn_type_lv = new char*[5];
 cidrs1.memo = new char*[5];
 cidrs1.begntime = new char*[5];
 cidrs1.endtime = new char*[5];

 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
 
    cidrs1.psn_idet_type[i] = new char[50];
    cidrs1.psn_type_lv[i] = new char[50];
    cidrs1.memo[i] = new char[50];
    cidrs1.begntime[i] = new char[50];
    cidrs1.endtime[i] = new char[50];
 }


 cirs1.insuinforecordscount = 0;
 cidrs1.idetinforecordscount = 0;


int result = getclientinfo(gs1, cs1, cbrs1, cirs1, cidrs1, grs1);
```

even I tried upgrade PB to 2019 and upgraded my project as well, but it doesn't work, it probably I have done something wrong but I still have no idea,any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I have dealt with this but in looking at some old PB source code, I remember how frustrating it would be to import API calls to PB. What I do remember is that most everything is passed to the call by ref, so if you think it doesn't make sense to use it, try it anyway. I was always surprised when it started working. Good luck.

Comment: I have acomplished this issue though ,bro ,thank you